# Index Service Design - Sync / Async

Tags: java, interface, indexing

I have a requirement to index items. This service should run Sync or Async.

I started designing an Interface

```
public interface IndexService{
    public void index();
}
```

And two implementation, one for a Async Index:

```
public class AsyncIndex implements IndexService {

    public void index(){
        //... Creates a Thread and index the items
    }

}
```

And the other one to the Sync Index

```
public class SyncIndex implements IndexService {

    public void index(){
        //... Creates a Thread and index the items
    }

}
```

But now there is another design that is having a IndexService, who has a flag to execute as a async service or as a sync service:

```
public interface IndexService{
    public void index(int mode);
}
```

So now the implementation will know how to run base on that flag.

I know that the first design is better, but I need pros and cons to explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I go for first approach because

1- code is cleaner AsyncInex class only has codes related to async call and syncIndex would has its own code.
2- you can avoid else if

```
...
public void runService(IndexService service) {
     service.index()
}

// some where in your code
runService(new AsyncIndex());
// or
runService(new SyncIndex());
```

as you are working with interface "IndexService" you can always change implementation without changing clients code.
specially if you are using DI frameworks you can have the kick of it ;).

this is so important to not allowing client code know about the implementation. suppose situation where you are indexing, for instance, a database.
you want to do async index when data is huge or sync index when data is small.
caller should has no knowledge about the way Index is called. this way you can have different strategy in different situations without changing callers code. if you take the second approach you have to do some extra work.

Answer (score 1):

I say both.

Assume, you plan to use the second approach. Your implmentation may look like:

```
public SyncOrAsyncIndex implements IndexService {
public void index(int mode) {
    if(mode == 0) {
        //sync processing code
    } else if (mode == 1) {
        //async procesisng code
    }

}
```

That said, are you going to write all the implementation within this index method or SyncOrAsyncIndex class. That will possibly end up being unmanageable. 
So, the index method may end up like this:

```
public void index(int mode) {
    if(mode == 0) {
        new SyncIndex().index(); //for example
    } else if (mode == ) {
        new AsyncIndex().index(); //for example
    }
}
```

Assume, you decide on supporting a third mode. Imagine the plight of the index method or SyncOrAsyncIndex class. So, the first approach is needed.

So, as per "code to the interface" strategy the first approach is suggested. If the invoker is aware of the type of indexing, they can just instantiate the particular type and use it.

Else, along with the first approach the second one may be required as a factory or strategy to calculate which type of indexing to use based on the passed parameter. The invoker would then use the SyncIndex or AsyncIndex via SyncOrAsyncIndex.